# docker cp from local into container got strange user group

Tags: postgresql, docker

I start a latest offical postgres docker image pulled from `docker run --name postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=passwd -d postgres`

Then I'm running the following command, `docker cp colors.csv postgres:/colors.csv`.

But after the docker cp, the file copied is created in a strange user group, not as root.

```
xuanyue$ docker exec -it postgres ls -ahl
total 80K
drwxr-xr-x   1 root      root      4.0K Jul 16 18:54 .
drwxr-xr-x   1 root      root      4.0K Jul 16 18:54 ..
drwxr-xr-x   1 root      root      4.0K Jul  2 23:39 bin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root      root      4.0K Feb 23 23:23 boot
-rwxrwxrwx   1 120042327 120042327  251 Jul 16 18:38 colors.csv
```

Why is that? I know I could easily change it through chown but just curious

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a quite disturbing behavior, because the result is unexpected compared to what's written in the description of [`docker cp` in the docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/#extended-description) :

> The cp command behaves like the Unix `cp -a` command in that directories are copied recursively with permissions preserved if possible. Ownership is set to the user and primary group at the destination. For example, files copied to a container are created with `UID:GID` of the root user. Files copied to the local machine are created with the `UID:GID` of the user which invoked the `docker cp` command. However, if you specify the `-a` option, `docker cp` sets the ownership to the user and primary group at the source.

But I found many opened issues/PRs related to this behavior :

- [docker cp behavior changed](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/34096)
- [`docker cp` is not setting the right UID & GID to the destination file](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/1814)
- [Change uid/gid on `docker cp` and preserve it on `docker cp -a`](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/34099)

I think this is going to be patched in future versions of Docker; waiting for that, you have to assume that `UID:GID` of the local file is conserved after copying the file to a container. In your example, `colors.csv` have probably `UID=120042327` and `GID=120042327` on your host (check with `stat colors.csv` on your host), that's why you get this result in your container. Moreover, here, `120042327` does not match any user/group in the container, but if that was the case, you may have seen some weird user/group owning the file (the ones corresponding to `120042327` user/group).